# Building a C++ PCL library and using it in Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I'd like to build a PCL library, starting from an existing C++ code. This code has some dependencies (SDL, which is available as a NuGet package) and I'd like to know if it's feasible to integrate it in a Xamarin solution (which targets Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Mac).

More precisely, the code is hosted here : https://github.com/chunying/gaminganywhere/tree/master/ga/client

If so, do I need to use C++/CX language ?

Comment: Maybe you should try a POC and if facing any challenges post the question about resolving it.

Comment: Yes you're right :)